# Can't start couchdb due to deprecation of scheduler_bind_type in Erlang/OTP 18

Tags: fedora, systemctl

I tried starting couchdb:

```
asedsami@localhost ~> sudo systemctl start couchdb.service
Job for couchdb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status couchdb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

which failed to start.

```
asedsami@localhost ~> couchdb -h
cat: /usr/bin/../releases/start_erl.data: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/couchdb: line 47: /usr/bin/../erts-/bin/erlexec: No such file or directory
```

I then tried to get the full log:

```
asedsami@localhost ~> sudo journalctl -u couchdb.service
Aug 10 17:19:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 10 17:19:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 10 17:19:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start CouchDB Server.
Aug 10 17:19:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Aug 10 17:19:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped CouchDB Server.
Aug 10 17:19:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting CouchDB Server...
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: =WARNING REPORT==== 10 Aug-2020::17:19:23.063486 ===
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: A call to erlang:system_flag(scheduler_bind_type, _) was
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: made. The scheduler_bind_type argument is deprecated and
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: scheduled for removal in Erlang/OTP 18. For more
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: information see the erlang:system_flag/2 documentation.
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: {"init terminating in do_boot",{{nocatch,{error,{app_would_not_start,sasl}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"src/couch.erl"},{line,43}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: init terminating in do_boot ({{nocatch,{error,{app_would_not_start,sasl}}},[{couch,start,0,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: [1B blob data]
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain couchdb[7903]: Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start CouchDB Server.
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped CouchDB Server.
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: couchdb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 10 17:19:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start CouchDB Server.
```

so there's a problem with `scheduler_bind_type` being deprecated in Erlang/OTP 18 which I don't know how to fix and I appreciate any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

You’d probably get the best answer by filing a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?component=couchdb&product=Fedora) to the maintainer of the Fedora package.  The maintainer, Peter Lemenkov, also maintains the erlang packages in Fedora and should be able to provide insight.

Comment: When googling `init terminating in do_boot couchdb fedora` I landed here. Just in case this is relevant to somebody else I submitted a bug for that: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1914990